# Threads never end when a new terminal is invoked from Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, db2, command-line-arguments, db2-luw

I have several commands what I need run with a Java program:

```
> db2cmd -i "db2 -tvsf \"C:\file1.sql\""
> db2cmd -i "db2 -tvsf \"C:\file2.sql\""
```

I create a new thread by every one, but the threads never end. db2cmd opens a new command prompt where you can input db2 commands. But the [official IBM documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002036.html) says you can use -i flag for running it on the same command window.

```
public class DirectoryRunner {
public static void main(String[] args){
  File f = new File("file1.sql");
  String cmd =  "db2cmd -i \"db2 -tvsf \\\"" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\\\"\""
  try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    IOThreadHandler outputHandler = new IOThreadHandler(
        p.getInputStream());
    outputHandler.start();
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(outputHandler.getOutput());

  } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private static class IOThreadHandler extends Thread {
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        IOThreadHandler(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public void run() {
            Scanner br = null;
            try {
                br = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = null;
                while (br.hasNextLine()) {
                    line = br.nextLine();
                    output.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        }

        public StringBuilder getOutput() {
            return output;
        }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace all of that code with `new ProcessBuilder("db2cmd", "-i, "db2 -tvsf \"" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\"").inheritIO().start().waitFor()`.  That will allow you to see both the command’s output and its standard error, which probably is telling you the file was not found, since the backslashes in its path are not escaped the way the double quotes (`"`) are.

Comment: Why would you want to shell out commands instead of just running the SQL directly via JDBC from your inside your application?

Answer (score 0):

Use `db2cmd` with both the `-i` (inherit window) and `-c` (close window on exit) command line options.